# C#, date from string, time zone, daylight savings

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Say I have the string `"1 December 2012, 8:00:00"`

I know that it is AEST time (regardless where the server is), with whatever daylight saving state at that time (1st Dec), but I want to store it in the database as UTC.

How do I convert it to UTC, treating the string as AEST regardless where the server is?

Comment: Look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615538/parse-a-date-string-into-a-certain-timezone-supporting-daylight-saving-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615538/parse-a-date-string-into-a-certain-timezone-supporting-daylight-saving-time) It may help.

Comment: Use the TimeZoneInfo class.  You'll need to use the full name of the time zone, it is "AUS Eastern Standard Time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first initialize a `System.DateTime` which gets the `DateTime` from the string you've specified above. Then, you may use `System.DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` which converts the value of the current `System.DateTime` object to Coordinated Universal Time and store it in the database.

**Example**

```
DateTime AEST = DateTime.Parse("1 December 2012, 8:00:00"); //Initialize a new DateTime of name AEST which gets a System.DateTime from 1 December 2012, 8:00:00
DateTime UTC = AEST.ToUniversalTime(); //Initialize a new DateTime of name UTC which converts the value from AEST to Coordinated Universal Time
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(UTC.ToString()); //Writes 12/1/2012 6:00:00 AM
```

**Notice**: If you are willing to convert a time from one time zone to another, you may use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo, destinationTimeZone)` where `dateTime` is the `DateTime` you would like to convert, `sourceTimeZone` is the time zone of the `DateTime` you would like to convert and `destinationTimeZone` is the time zone you would to get from `dateTime`

**Example**

```
string _date = "1 December 2012, 8:00:00"; //Initializes a new string of name _date as "1 December 2012, 8:00:00"
string targetTimeZone = "W. Australia Standard Time"; //Initializes a new string of name targetTimeZone as "W. Australia Standard Time"
DateTime sourceDateTime = DateTime.Parse(_date); //Initializes a new DateTime of name sourceDateTime which gets a valid DateTIme object from 1 December 2012, 8:00:00
DateTime AEST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(targetTimeZone)); //Initializes a new DateTime which converts the time zone from sourceDateTime assuming that sourceDateTime's TimeZone is the local time zone of the machine to an W. Australia Standard Time time zone of name AEST
```

This will convert `1 December 2012, 8:00:00` assuming that its time zone is the local time zone of the machine (e.g `Egypt Standard Time: (GMT+02:00) Cairo`) to `W. Australia Standard Time: (GMT+08:00) Perth` which will be `12/1/2012 2:00:00 PM`.

For list of time zones, see [Microsoft Time Zone Index Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx)

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: How would the website know that the string is in AEST? (The server can be anywhere)

Comment: @aximili `AEST` is just a variable which is used to get a valid `DateTime` object from a `string` using `DateTime.Parse(string s)`. I do not really think that the time must be in AEST to be parsed. Have a nice day :)

Comment: That means it can give different results depending on the server location. I need to treat the string as AEST regardless where the server is.

Comment: @aximili I've updated my answer! I hope you get your problem resolved as soon as possible. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can parse the date with `DateTime.TryParse` and get it into a `DateTime` structure, you can then call `ToUniversalTime` to convert to UTC.

For example:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime utcDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dt))
{
    utcDate = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    // store utcDate in database
}
else
{
    // error, unable to parse the date
}
```

Assuming, of course, that your local time is AEST, or the date/time string that you're parsing has the timezone specifier.

If your local time is something else and there's no timezone specifier, then you need to parse the date, add or subtract the offset from your time zone to match AEST, and then call `ToUniversalTime`.

Comment: "then you need to parse the date, add or subtract the offset from your time zone to match AEST, and then call ToUniversalTime" <-- that is my question, how?

Comment: @aximili: I cover parsing the date above. To add or subtract hours, call `DateTime.AddHours` (or, rarely, `AddMinutes`). Or are you asking how to figure out how many hours to add/subtract?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Picrofo EGY, esr and White Dragon, I created this function that solves it

```
public static DateTimeOffset CreateDateWithTimezone(string dateStr, TimeZoneInfo tzi)
{
  DateTimeOffset dtoTzi = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tzi);

  DateTimeOffset dto;
  if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateStr + " " + dtoTzi.ToString("zzz"), out dto))
    throw new Exception("Failed to parse date: " + dateStr + " " + dtoTzi.ToString("zzz"));

  if (tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)
  {
    TimeSpan offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(dto);
    string offsetStr = (offset.TotalHours < 0 ? "" : "+") + offset.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + offset.Minutes.ToString("00");

    if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateStr + " " + offsetStr, out dto))
      throw new Exception("Failed to parse date: " + dateStr + " " + dtoTzi.ToString("zzz"));
  }

  return dto;
}
```

Usage:

```
string dateStr = "1 December 2012, 08:00:00";
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset dtoUtc = CreateDateWithTimezone(dateStr, tzi).ToUniversalTime();

Response.Write("dtoUtc is " + dtoUtc);
```

It will print out

> dtoUtc is 30/11/2012 9:00:00 PM +00:00

Perfect!