# How to Parse a Date Time with TimeZone Info

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have following string ,

> Thu Sep 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

I tried with following but it's faling.

```
   var twDate = DateTime.Parse("Thu Sep 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) ");
```

Can not use replace , as IST wont be fixed. Any Ideas?

Comment: Is the time zone part always in brackets after a space though? If so, you could detect *that* and parse the rest. (I'd suggest parsing it to a DateTimeOffset, given that that's the information being presented...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615538/parse-a-date-string-into-a-certain-timezone-supporting-daylight-saving-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trim the time zone abbreviation off using normal string operations, then specify a custom date and time format string. For example:

```
// After trimming
string text = "Thu Sep 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    text,
    "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dto);
```

Note the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` here - you almost certainly *don't* want to parse using the current thread's current culture.

Answer (score 0):

If your string always has the same format and length, you could use this to get UTC:

```
String dtstr = "Thu Sep 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)";
int zoneMin = int.Parse(dtstr.Substring(29, 2)) * 60 + int.Parse(dtstr.Substring(31, 2));
if (dtstr.Substring(28, 1) == "+") zoneMin = -zoneMin;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dtstr.Substring(0, 24)).AddMinutes(zoneMin);
```